# Displaying the number without having to refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, page-refresh

```
function countComments() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/comments/' + id,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: 'true',
        success: function(comments) {
            console.log(comments + "count");

            $('.btn-dis').html('total' + comments.length );
        }
    });
}

$('#btnComment').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('post comment');
    // pass in the form object
    postComment( $(this).parent().parent(), 'comment' );
    // title, body, refId, commentorId, commentorName
    countComments();
    $('textarea#comment').val('');
});
```

Right now, I have to refresh it every time I post comment. The total should display the number of comments "automatically" or "instantly" after click button to post comment.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Try to add cache: false for that ajax call..

Comment: i think you need to call countComments in postComment, after post you should call countComments.

Comment: @Hardy - tried but it didn't work or rather do nothing after I tested a few times.

Comment: did you try what i suggested? call countComments in postComment

Comment: @akbarali - ah you mean calling countComments in postComment function?

Comment: yes call the countComments in postComment function not in click function

Comment: @akbarali - yes I called countComments in postComment function and it doesn't update the number immediately after post :(

Comment: Make postComment processing code to send comment count back after processing the comment and update comment count in postComment success callback..

Comment: How to vote the answers of akbarali and hardy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your comment count on postComment callback.

Like:

```
function postComment() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/comments/add',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {

          // Comment accepted.. 
          if (data.status == "ok") {

            console.log(data.comment_count);
          } 
        }
    });
}
```

and set your server to pass comment post results with json like:

```
{status: "ok", comment_count: 19283}
```

Answer (score 1):

what about using setInterval for your problem this will update your comment count every 3 seconds. if you want can you change this time its given in miliseconds

```
$('#btnComment').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('post comment');
        // pass in the form object
        postComment( $(this).parent().parent(), 'comment' );
        // title, body, refId, commentorId, commentorName
        countComments()//loads the comment after clicking button instantly
        setInterval(countComments(),3000);//and check for   update counts every 3 seconds
        $('textarea#comment').val('');
    });
```

Comment: Why set interval after clicking send button? Why not all the time? Like when document loaded..

Comment: user may want it at this way and i didn't want to change his/her code without knowing the whole code

Comment: @Semir Turgay - tried your method, but it didn't show the number after i clicked to post comment. I had to refresh again to see the number update

Comment: What i wanted to see is the update of the total of the comments immediately after clicking button. There is no way around except clicking refresh button to see the update number of comments

Answer (score 0):

your comment countComments(); get called once the function
postComment( $(this).parent().parent(), 'comment' ); return success or true on success full comment posted

also use async:false

it should be like

$('#btnComment').click(function(e) {

```
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('post comment');
    // pass in the form object
    if(postComment( $(this).parent().parent(), 'comment' )){
    // title, body, refId, commentorId, commentorName
    countComments();
    }
    $('textarea#comment').val('');
```

});